# The oldbar extension isn't compatible with Firefox 4. Is there a way around this?

Tags: firefox, awesomebar

Namely, is there some equivalent extension around that runs in FF4, or is there some way to alter oldbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moot. The newest version *does* run in FF4.

Answer (score 0):

If it ever doesn't, then look for `checkCompatibility` and `checkUpdateSecurity` settings online.

Here is what I've added to my `about:config` because I've a nightly build for optimization purposes...

[image]